# Drupal migrate nodes with taxonomy

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, data-migration, drupal-taxonomy

I have a drupal 7 installation, i want to migrate nodes with associated taxonomy terms. I tried with migrate module, but it imports only nodes, not terms associated, even if i have the same structure of taxonomy vocabulary and same machine name of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) and [uuid_features](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features) modules to import/export your terms and nodes. Just follow the instructions on drupal.org pages.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to import taxonomy and then while importing node configure `yml` by using `plugin: migration` on the `yml` file, then you can migrate nodes with associated taxonomy terms both.